# Display Alerts on Modal with Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I am using Spring Boot and thymeleaf for my web application. For implementing Forgot password feature I am having modal in login.html.After submitting the form to controller, to display success or error alerts on modal I used AJAX call. But the alerts are displayed on login page not on modal. Below is the code..

LoginController.java

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/forgotPassword", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView processForgotPasswordForm(ModelAndView modelAndView, @RequestParam("email") String email) {
            UserDetails userDetails = userService.findUserByEmail(email);
            if (null == userDetails) {
                modelAndView.addObject("errorMessage", "Entered email doesn't exist in records");
                modelAndView.setViewName("login");
                return modelAndView;
            }
            boolean generatedToken = userService.generatePassResetToken(userDetails);
            if (generatedToken) {
                modelAndView.addObject("successMessage", Constants.PASSWORD_EMAIL_LINK);
            }
            modelAndView.setViewName("login");
            return modelAndView;
        }
```

app.js

```
$(function(){
    $("#passForgot").on('submit',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();    

     $form= $(this);

     $.post("forgotPassword", $(this).serialize(),function(data){
      $feedback = $("<div>").html(data).find(".form-feedback").hide();

      $form.prepend($feedback)[0].reset();
      $feedback.fadeIn(500);
     });
    }); 
    })
```

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/login.css}" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/js/app.js}"></script>
<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.modal-footer {
    border-top: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img th:src="@{/images/login.jpg}" class="img-responsive center-block"
            width="300" height="300" alt="Logo" />
        <form th:action="@{/login}" method="POST" class="form-signin">
            <h3 class="form-signin-heading" th:text="Welcome"></h3>
            <br /> <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName"
                required="required" th:placeholder="Username" class="form-control" />
            <br /> <input type="password" th:placeholder="Password"
                required="required" id="password" name="password"
                class="form-control" /> <br />
            <div>
                <input type='checkbox' name="remember-me-param" /> Remember Me<br />
            </div>
            <!-- <a href="forgotPassword">Forgot Password?</a><br> -->
            <br>
            <div align="center" th:if="${param.error}">
                <p style="font-size: 20; color: #FF1C19;">Username or Password
                    invalid, please verify</p>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="Submit"
                value="Login" type="Submit" th:text="Login"></button>
            <br> <br>
            <div class="container">
                <a href="#" data-target="#pwdModal" data-toggle="modal">Forgot
                    Password?</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>


    <!--modal-->
    <form action="forgotPassword" id="passForgot" method="post">
        <div id="pwdModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        <h1 class="text-center">LOGO</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <div th:if="${successMessage}"
                                            class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible form-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"
                                                aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                                            <div th:text=${successMessage}></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div th:if="${errorMessage}"
                                            class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible form-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"
                                                aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                                            <div th:text=${errorMessage}></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div
                                            style="font-size: 17px; line-height: 21px; margin-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 14px; color: #333333;"
                                            align="center">
                                            To reset your password, enter the email <br>address associated
                                            with your account below.<br> 
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <fieldset>
                                                <div class="form-group input-group has-feedback">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon"> <span
                                                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope "></span>
                                                    </span> <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address"
                                                        class="form-control" name="email"
                                                         required /> <span
                                                        class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>

                                                </div>
                                                <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
                                                    value="Send Email" type="submit">
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[Login Page with Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpQmU.png)

[Error alerts displaying on login form but not on modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qONQO.png)

What's wrong with this code ?